# Auto completing song titles and parsing a string

Tags: python, regex, parsing, itunes-store

I get this string via Python, using a request to a Shoutcast server:

> BEST SHOW EVER http://www.myradio.foo/xml/logos/showlogo.jpg Avicii Hey Brother

And I'd like to get a dict containing this:

`mystring[showtitle] = 'BEST SHOW EVER'
mystring[image] = 'http://www.myradio.foo/xml/logos/showlogo.jpg'
mystring[song] = 'Avicii hey brother'`

The string is always ASCII, and anything could be written after and before the link.

How can i parse that? I guess I need to use regex, but i heard they aren't very fast.

---

Also, the title needs a bit of tweaking, to look prettier.

> Avicii hey brother

Becomes

> Avicii - Hey Brother

What would you raccomend to do that? I thought about searching the title on iTunes and get from the first result all the data, but I'm not sure how to do that (all links for the iTunes API redirect me to the Apple SDK, that i would like to not use).

Comment: You've provided one string example `BEST SHOW EVER http://www.myradio.foo/xml/logos/showlogo.jpg Avicii Hey Brother`. Is there a more general form that you want to parse? For example, a string of Capitalized words, followed by a url, followed by a string of words ....

Comment: "I need to use regex, but i heard they aren't very fast." Regex is a concept used in many languages. It is fast in many contexts, and is probably slow in some limited situations. It is especially slow when used poorly, or in situations where it shouldn't be used in the first place.

Comment: If the image link always starts with the standard http, it should be pretty simple to split up the parts and return them individually with \1 \2 \3 like this: `(.+) (http:.+?) (.+)`.  However I'm not sure how you expect regex (or any automated system) to correctly separate the artist/title.  Even a human wouldn't be able to do that without prior knowledge of the song.

Comment: Thank you CAustin for the answer, that what i'll use. My idea is to send the title to some online database and get more info on the song, not use regex to separate artist and title.

Comment: I would worry about the format for splitting up the data before tweaking titles after the fact.

Comment: Split -> remove start/end spaces/tabs. What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong about the `dict()` Here is the updated solution that converts it into dict.

```
response = '''BEST SHOW EVER http://www.myradio.foo/xml/logos/showlogo.jpg Avicii Hey Brother'''

## parsing using named group
m = re.match("(?P<showtitle>.*?)\s+(?P<image>https?://\S+)\s+(?P<song>.+)", response);
mystring = m.groupdict()
print mystring['song']
```

You can not always convert the song name on your format always. Cause you don't know which one is song name, or which one album name. If its always fixed that the first word is the album name, then you can do this one:

```
print re.sub("^(\S+)\s", "\\1 - ", mystring['song'])
```

Comment: 0m0.009s of execution time for this solution, versus 0m0.011s of the other. I'll choose this because it's faster.

Answer (score 1):

Right, so you can get the dictionary as specified like this:

```
>>> s = 'BEST SHOW EVER http://www.myradio.foo/xml/logos/showlogo.jpg Avicii hey brother'
>>> mystring = dict(zip(('showtitle', 'image', 'song'), re.search('(.+) (http:.+?) (.+)', s).groups()))
>>> mystring
{'image': 'http://www.myradio.foo/xml/logos/showlogo.jpg', 'showtitle': 'BEST SHOW EVER', 'song': 'Avicii Hey Brother'}
```

Then you can 'prettify' the `song` item by doing this:

```
>>> mystring[song] = out[song].title()
>>> mystring[song]
'Avicii Hey Brother'
```

Comment: @EdoardoCodeglia They are cool, but generally they should be avoided, especially in Python. I judged it to be acceptable here.

Comment: i usually put comments before oneliners to make the code more readable in case i forget what the line does or another programmer looks at it

Comment: @EdoardoCodeglia That line would be fairly self-explanatory for a decent Python programmer, although my computing teacher insists that I should comment every line for those exact reasons...

Comment: EVERY LINE? That seems like an exaggeration for me!
I usually comment every line when i send codes to my classmates